# Unable to get the length of an array inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the length of the first array in an array (should return 2010), but I can't seem to do so with .length. The picture attached is a snapshot of the console when I run:

```
console.log(marker)
```

[image]

When I try to run the following, it returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

```
console.log(marker[0].length)
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

```
console.log(marker.length)
//returns 3
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Can't seem to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? When/how is exactly marker created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the issue with such types of unexpected results is the *blueish) small question mark on the right side. It means that the result was evaluated after your code finished executing, aka async issue.

I would suggest that you see in your code where the async call appears and await it.

Comment: Yup, that solved my issue! Had to wait for the results then I could access it, thanks!